# how do I replace the user first input with current input when dealing with c-string

Tags: c++, c, string

I am having issue trying to replace a user input with other user input.

For instance if the user input "I love dog" and then we ask them do they want to input other string and they input "I eat a lot of icecream".

How do I replace the user first input with the current one?

```
// Function Prototype
int countVowels(char * str);
int countCons(char * str);

int main()
{

const int SIZE = 81;          // Max size of the array
                              //const int V_SIZE = 6;         // Size of the vowel array
char newSentence[SIZE];
char userString[SIZE];
//char vowels[V_SIZE] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
char choice;                  // To hold the menu choice
char *strPtr = userString;    // Declare and initialize the pointer
char *sentPtr = newSentence;
                              // Get the string from the user

cout << "Please enter a string. (Maximum of 80 characters) :\n\n";
cin.getline(userString, SIZE);
do{
    // Display the menu and get a choice
    cout << "\n\nA. Count the number of vowels in the string \n";
    cout << "B. Count the number of consonants in the string \n";
    cout << "C. Enter another string \n";
    cout << "D. Exit the program \n\n";
    cout << "Please make your selection: ";
    cin >> choice;

    // Menu selections
    if (tolower(choice) == 'a')
    {
        countVowels(userString);
        cout << "This string contains " << countVowels(userString);
        cout << " vowels. \n";
    }
    else if (tolower(choice) == 'b')
    {
        countCons(userString);
        cout << "This string contains " << countCons(userString);
        cout << " consonants. \n";
    }

    else if (tolower(choice) == 'c')
    {
        cout << "Please enter other string: ";
        cin.getline(newSentence, SIZE);
        userString.replace();
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    }
    else
    {
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }

} while (choice != 'D');
}
```

I am having the issue with menu selection C. How do I replace userString with newSentence?

Comment: No need for c tag if your code is written in C++.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Just remove the `c` tag from the tag list `c++` `c` `string` from your question.

Comment: How about: `strcpy(userString, newSentence);` ? Anyway, why use C-style strings instead `std::string` when using C++ ?

Comment: Instead of `cin.getline(newSentence, SIZE);` you can use `cin.getline(userString, SIZE);` . So no need to replace. Just overwriting.

Comment: `countVowels(userString);
        cout << "This string contains " << countVowels(userString);
        ` and `countCons(userString);
        cout << "This string contains " << countCons(userString);
        ` the first countVowels(userString) and countCons(userString) are useless because they presumably return a string (judging by your use of these functions in the cout stream), but they are giving the string to anything.

Answer (score 1):

I hope no need of two array declaration for your purpose. instead of  cin.getline(newSentence, SIZE); use cin.getline(userString, SIZE); it will hold the new string by overwriting.

```
else if (tolower(choice) == 'c')
{
    cout << "Please enter other string: ";
    cin.getline(userString, SIZE);
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

}
```

If you looking some thing else, define it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in function in C called strcpy to overwrite one string with another.

```
strcpy(userString, newSentence);
```

The string on the left will now become the newSentence string.